# How to remove files from Varnish-cache

Tags: caching, varnish, cloudcontrol

I'm developing a game in js/php. When I first uploaded my project, it contained a file named "index.html" with nonsensical content (only the word "bla" and a facebook-like-button). I later deleted that "index.html" so that requests to the domain would hit my "index.php" instead (wich contains the actual game).

This happend over a week ago, and i still see people (friends i asked to test the game) getting this dumb "index.html" shown when they open the site in their browsers. I also see this happening to roughly 1/3rd of the browsers when requesting screenshots via [browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/7c49d51fb967cdb22df42d10b626d97b99120853) or browsershots.org.

I'm assiming the index.html is still cached by cloudcontroles Varnish-cache, but i can't find any possibility to clear this cache for my site. How can i do this or what can i do to get rid of this cached version?

For anyone who wants to test this live: http://dotgame2.cloudcontrolled.com/ (note that this dosn't happen always and for everyone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [cache breakers](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#performance--caching) dependent on deployment version. You can also try our ***.cloudcontrolapp.com** [routing tier](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#routing-tier) which do not provide caching at all - http://dotgame2.cloudcontrolapp.com.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, mkorszun. Sadly, this doesn't really help me - i actually want the cache to be used, so *.cloudcontrolled is the domain i want. The cache-breaking would only work for sub-requests to css- or js-files or on-site-links where i could add some sort of changing parameters like the `DEP_VERSION` - but the "broken" part here is the initial request, and i don't want to publish http://dotgame2.cloudcontrolled.com/?add_some_parameter_to_avoid_caching everywhere when the plain url (http://dotgame2.cloudcontrolled.com/) should be enough.

Comment: I found a (very ugly) solution: I deleted the app and created a new one with another name (it's http://dotgame.cloudcontrolled.com/ now). I had to reconfigure everything and setup the database again, but since the game is still in develeopment mode i didn't have any users to care about. I'll accept your answer because it's likely to help someone else with a similar problem even though it didn't really help me.

Comment: Best results are probably achieved by having the / or index served via the APP_NAME.cloudcontrolapp.com subdomain and referencing all assets e.g. JS and CSS files via the APP_NAME.cloudcontrolled.com subdomain. This way you can cache assets for a long time and just use cache breakers by changing the references in the index files. You can use the DEP_VERSION env variable for this.